# How to design Date in DraggableScrollableSheet

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: Date]

[image: Time]

How to design Date in DraggableScrollableSheet because the years are too deep and close to the month. How to make a design like time design.

Code Date:

```
void _showDatePickerBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            ),
            color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.001),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: ScrollConfiguration(
                behavior:
                    ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(dragDevices: {
                  PointerDeviceKind.touch,
                  PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
                }),
                child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  initialChildSize: 0.5,
                  minChildSize: 0.2,
                  maxChildSize: 1,
                  builder: (_, controller) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                          mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                          initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                          onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                            //_selectedReadingDate = newDateTime;
                            _readingDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy')
                                .format(newDateTime)
                                .toString();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Code Time:

```
void _showTimePickerBottomSheet(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
            setState(() {});
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            ),
            color: const Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.001),
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: ScrollConfiguration(
                behavior:
                    ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(dragDevices: {
                  PointerDeviceKind.touch,
                  PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
                }),
                child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  initialChildSize: 0.5,
                  minChildSize: 0.2,
                  maxChildSize: 1,
                  builder: (_, controller) {
                    return Container(
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(25.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(25.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 200,
                        child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                          mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
                          initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                          onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                            _readingTime = DateFormat('hh:mm a')
                                .format(newDateTime)
                                .toString();
                            _readingTimeIn24HourFormat = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss')
                                .format(newDateTime)
                                .toString();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I set initialChildSize, minChildSize, maxChildSize I have set the same. But for Date years too curved inwards. Is there a way to make the years not curve inwards? Is there anyone who can help?